# Installing mysql gem on OSX El Capitan, RVM, for legacy rails app - MySQL dmg / brew

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Supporting a legacy app written in rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7

Upgraded from OS X 10.9 to 10.11 1-2 months ago without issue, have RVM installed (rvm 1.26.11 (latest)), had MySQL 5.6.10 installed via brew, legacy app had mysql gem working in its gemset.

Attempting to get an anaconda2 project working mysql library files were not being found, and I uninstalled via brew an older version while troubleshooting (non 5.6.10) and afterwards all rails applications no longer were able to start (missing mysql dependencies).

I could not get anything working with brew, and after cleaning up all warnings using `brew doctor` I still wasn't able to get MySQL running (server) so I decided to start over.

Uninstalled brew using `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

Re-installed MySQL using `http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-5.6.27-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg`

Was able to get data re-imported into server and mysql client connecting correctly from terminal.

At some point during troubleshooting I had uninstalled mysql via `gem uninstall mysql` and now trying to re-install the gem I get the following error:

```
kh@MBP ~/c/main/code/rails/main % gem install mysql --no-ri --no-rdoc -- --with-mysql-config='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/kh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/kh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@ruby-187/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@ruby-187/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

All the MySQL files appear to be in the correct places:

```
kh@MBP ~/c/main/code/rails/main % ls -l /usr/local/mysql
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff  27 Mar 18 15:48 /usr/local/mysql -> mysql-5.6.27-osx10.8-x86_64
kh@MBP ~/c/main/code/rails/main % ls -l /usr/local/mysql/bin/*mysql*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff      1551 Sep 18  2015 /usr/local/mysql/bin/msql2mysql
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff   4750576 Sep 18  2015 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff   4838512 Sep 18  2015 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_client_test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff  16355200 Sep 18  2015 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_client_test_embedded
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kh  staff      6425 Sep 18  2015 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by removing these RVM rubies/gems, upgrading RVM, and recompiling ruby 1.8.7 and re-installing all my gems. Seems like a migration to el capitan issue with an old version of RVM masquerading as a specific mysql issue.